# build website in hosting then transfer it to vps

Tags: php, web, hosting, web-hosting, vps

I'm trying to move my site from hosting to my vps but didn't work.

What I'm doing is build website in :

```
zyro.com
```

Then move it but when I'm trying to open my website (After the transfer of the site) show to me empty web page.

And I'm transfer my website to another hosting and it's working 100% but not working on VPS.

Is there any program should I install it on my VPS ?

Update :

the error was :

```
Notice: Undefined variable: lang in /home/www/html/public_html/zyro/1.php on line 1

Notice: Undefined variable: lang in /home/www/html/public_html/zyro/1.php on line 80

Notice: Undefined variable: lang in /home/www/html/public_html/zyro/1.php on line 159
```

And in the line 1 there is :

```
<?php if ($lang == 'en') { ?>
```

And line 80 there is :

```
<?php } else if ($lang == 'ar') { ?>
```

And line 159 there is :

```
<?php } else if ($lang == 'fr') { ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable PHP error reporting in your PHP.ini. Add this line (or modify existing):

```
display_errors = on
```

You can post errors here, after.

Or, if you don't know how to do it try put in PHP script (it won't show parse errors, though)

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

And don't forget to remove this lines, after you'll fix it.

Comment: How do you get `$lang`? Is it defined in code or got from user? Where it's defined?

Comment: Find file, with `<?php if ($lang == 'en') { ?>`. I can't find it

Comment: it's located in : 1.php